# Check if wx.TextCtrl has been deselected, wxpython

Tags: python, wxpython, wxwidgets

Is there some event that checks if the wx.TextCtrl widget has been deselected?

Heres an example of what I want:

```
myTextbox.Bind(wx.EVT_DESELECT, self.myfunction)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you are looking for the [EVT_KILL_FOCUS](http://wiki.wxpython.org/Surviving%20with%20wxEVT%20KILL%20FOCUS%20under%20Microsoft%20Windows).